# To search text layers of DjVu -files

Tags: finder, search

I would like to expand the system search to DjVu -files or find an alternative way to do this. 
My current OS X is Yosemite 10.10.2 but this can a Unix tool tool.
DjVu contains an OCR text layer, making it easy to perform copy and paste and text search operations. 
The search is also more efficient than in PDF.

**How can you search Djvu files also efficiently in a system search?**
I am open about tools. 
It can be Finder but I would prefer first efficient terminal tool.

Comment: DjVu files are images. The only way to search them would be by filename, just like any other images on your system.

Comment: @tubedogg Your last statement is not true! DjVu can contain an OCR text layer, making it easy to perform copy and paste and text search operations. This is also far more efficient than in PDF.